# How much of the Linux kernel is currently coded in rust?

Tags: linux-kernel, rust

Its a curiosity thing, but I would like to know How much of the Linux kernel is currently coded in rust ? I means in percent, and if you known it which part ? is there only drivers or is it real part of the kernel in pure rust ?

NB : from the github.com/torvalds/linux page there is a statistic that report no rust.

```
C 98.3%
Assembly 0.7%
Shell 0.4%
Makefile 0.2%
Python 0.2%
Perl 0.1%
Other 0.1%
```

Comment: "_I not able to dig into the source of Linux kernel to make stats on numbers of line written in rust_" - why not? It's freely available

Comment: go to the Linux kernel source on github ... search for file `.rs`

Comment: It is still massively C code, but expect Rust usage to increase.

Comment: That doesn't say no rust. It says "Other 0.1%", which reasonably means everything else rounded up in that.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because as a trivia question with a frequently changing answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Running [`scc`](https://github.com/boyter/scc) on the current kernel tree shows:

```
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Language                 Files     Lines   Blanks  Comments     Code Complexity
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
C                        33535  23766166  3418052   2665352 17682762    2350608
C Header                 24532   9561797   730157   1434776  7396864      51421
[…]
Rust                        64     20887     1538      9857     9492        877
[…]
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Total                    79107  37438114  4702768   4249053 28486293    2424920
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

so 0.03% of the code (ignoring comments) is written in Rust. For now that’s mostly [support code](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.8-rc3/source/rust); 6.8 will likely have [one phy driver](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.8-rc3/source/drivers/net/phy/ax88796b_rust.rs) written in Rust.